# Wordpress plugin load js and css on demand

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, plugins

I created plugin with shortcode. I want to load js and css of my plugin only if i use the plugin(the shortcode in my post). I found few examples and i created something like this. Is it correct way? Everything works but i can't see these scripts in page source (i checked Firefox and chrome)

```
   public function __construct(){       
        add_shortcode( $this->tag, array($this, 'run_yoolek' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',  array( $this, 'register_my_script' ) );  
    }

    public function run_yoolek(){

        wp_enqueue_style('yoolek-googlemap-simple-css');
        wp_enqueue_script('google-maps');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'yoolek-googlemap-simple-js' );

        ob_start();
        ...
        return ob_get_clean();
    } 

    public function register_my_script() {
        wp_register_style( 'yoolek-googlemap-simple-css',plugins_url( '/style.css' , __FILE__ ) );
        wp_register_script( 'google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAM10sMY' );
        wp_register_script( 'yoolek-googlemap-simple-js', plugins_url( '/script.js' , __FILE__ ) );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

wp_enqueue_style() and wp_enqueue_script() doesn't work in this place, you should use them in another function, for example, my_scripts_method()  for wp_enqueue_scripts hook.

```
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'my_scripts_method') );
```

Comment: Hi thx for answer. What does it mean "doesn't work in this place"- i tested it and it works but I don't know if it is correct way to do it. I am looking for best solution. You want me to move staff from  function run_yoolek to my_script_method?(enqueues). Do you think the rest is ok?

Comment: yes, I think, you should move wp_enqueue_script call to your register_my_script() function, after wp_register_script() calls